# Create an Encoding function for a 32 byte array in C? And decode too from a python function

Tags: c, decode, encode

Hey guys I'd like to know how to encode a 32 integer array as similar to the python function below?
Below is the python code:

```
def encodePublicKey(key, key_type):
 return b"\x42" + key + b"\x13\x37" + key_type.encode("US-ASCII")
```

Below is the C code that I have written ( I do believe there are some errors)

```
#include<stdio.h>

uint8_t value[33] = 
{
   0xED, 0xD3, 0xF5, 0x5C, 0x1A, 0x63, 0x12, 0x58,
   0xD6, 0x9C, 0xF7, 0xA2, 0xDE, 0xF9, 0xDE, 0x14,
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10,
   0x00,
};

void Encode(uint8_t *value) {

}
int main(){
    uint8_t value[33];
    Encode(&value);
}
```

I'd like to know how to encode and decode the byte array.
Thanks.

Comment: We generally [don't take code translation requests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265825) here. Instead, please try to use full English sentences to explain *what the C code should do*.

Answer (score -1):

`encodePublicKey` doesn't encode anything. It concatenates bytes sequences, which can be done using `memcpy`.

```c
// On error, *buf_ptr is NULL and errno is set.
void encode_public_key(
   const char* key,
   size_t key_size,
   const char *key_type,
   char **buf_ptr,
   size_t *buf_size_ptr
) {
   size_t key_type_len =  strlen( key_type );
   size_t buf_size = 1 + key_size + 2 + key_type_len;

   char *buf = malloc( buf_size );
   if ( buf == NULL ) {
      *buf_ptr = NULL;
      *buf_size_ptr = 0
      return;
   }

   char *p = buf;
   *p = 0x42;                            ++p;
   memcpy( p, key, key_size );           p += key_size;
   *p = 0x13;                            ++p;
   *p = 0x37;                            ++p;
   memcpy( p, key_type, key_type_len );  p += key_size;

   *buf_ptr = buf;
   *buf_size_ptr = buf_size;
}
```

Example usage:

```c
const char *key[] = {
   0xED, 0xD3, 0xF5, 0x5C, 0x1A, 0x63, 0x12, 0x58,
   0xD6, 0x9C, 0xF7, 0xA2, 0xDE, 0xF9, 0xDE, 0x14,
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10,
};

int main( void ) {
   char *encoded_key;
   size_t encoded_key_size;

   encode_public_key( 
      key,
      sizeof( key ) / sizeof( *key ),
      "???",
      &encoded_key, 
      &encoded_key_size
   );

   if ( !encoded_key ) {
      perror( NULL );
      return 1;
   }

   // Use encoded_key + encoded_key_size here.

   free( encoded_key );

   return 0;
}
```